# How can I enable REST API on my WordPress web site?

Tags: wordpress, rest

I tried with this line, is it the right way?

[image]

I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'DOWNLOAD_JOBS' in /home/nplusbic/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpml-translation-management/classes/ATE/REST/Download.php:27 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/nplusbic/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/API/REST/Adaptor.php(18): WPML\TM\ATE\REST\Download->get_routes() 
#1 /home/nplusbic/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/API/REST/Base.php(23): WPML\Rest\Adaptor->add_hooks() 
#2 /home/nplusbic/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/action-filter-loader/class-wpml-action-filter-loader.php(151): WPML\Rest\Base->add_hooks() 
#3 /home/nplusbic/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/action-filter-loader/class-wpml-action-filter-loader.php(121): WPML_Action_Filter_Loader->run_factory(Object(WPML\TM\REST\FactoryLoader)) 
#4 /home/nplusbic/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): WPML_Action_Filter_Loader->deferred_loader(Object(WP_REST_Server)) 
#5 /home/nplusbic/public_h in /home/nplusbic/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpml-translation-management/classes/ATE/REST/Download.php on line 27
There has been a critical error on your website.
```

Comment: You'll get better answers if mention that it pertains to a certain plugin. I read that article on WPML and it says for most that its a false positive. Do you have plugin installed to disable the rest api?

Comment: I tried checking your site for the rest api but your site seems to be down

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to enable it.

https://yoursite.com/wp-json/namespace/route

Here is a good resource on using it:

[Rest API reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/)

Answer (score 0):

It is enabled by default.

You can access Wordpress REST API by going to `YOUR_WEBSITE.COM/wp-json`.

Comment: I tried this `http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/` and it opened the HTML page?

Comment: @Volatil3 Also had a 404 page in HTML. My solution was to turn off a plugin which blocked API requests.